# AngularJS Getting Syntax Error in Returned JSON from HTTP.JSONP

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am having trouble getting the NYTimes API to return the JSON correctly. I am sure it is something I am doing wrong versus them. I tried this using the ESPN API and it worked fine. Not sure what I am missing. Here is a look at the code.

```
app.controller('espn', function($scope,$http){
      //var url = "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/news/headlines/top?limit=9&apikey=n39jrj4s97tvhxym4qgacnrd&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
      var url = "http://api.nytimes.com/svc/news/v3/content/all/all/.json?&limit=20&api-key=1f6ef65ff5bb290bdcb01da786c788de:2:67858849&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
     $http.jsonp(url)
        .success( function(data){
            console.log(data);
      });
});
```

I get this error in my error console. 
    **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :**

Here is the plunker. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nrdQqgc5W4K3Vu7oC8QU)

Comment: That URL isn't JSONP.  You can't do that.

Comment: so your saying it does process JSONP. how did you know that?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP You can only use JSONP to send a request to an endpoint that specifically allows JSONP.  If you look at the HTTP response with the callback parameter, you must see a function call.

Comment: You could make a proxy on your own server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sinse you are calling JSONP, it means that the returned json should be wrappet in a function.

for example:

```
JSON_CALLBACK({"status":"OK"});//this is actually how the server suppose to answer back
```

So, I see that you send `callback=JSON_CALLBACK`, but the server does not reply with function call to `JSON_CALLBACK`

Youll need somehow to force the server to support [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

If you go to:
http://api.nytimes.com/svc/news/v3/content/all/all/.json?&limit=20&api-key=1f6ef65ff5bb290bdcb01da786c788de:2:67858849&callback=JSON_CALLBACK
youll see that the server is not responding as JSONP

you can maybe hack it, have a look here:
http://jquery-howto.blogspot.co.il/2013/09/jquery-cross-domain-ajax-request.html

Comment: I mean it is up to the server to do such a thing if they want to correct? I don't think I can force the server to do such a thing.

Comment: you cant, if the API documentation says so, so you will be able to. Sometime api are blocking that in order to prevent robots scanning the ajax servers, but if I look at the server response, you can make your server call their server and than you will return the message to the javascript.

Comment: I see that now. So I guess if it doesn't support it, then there is no way of forcing it to, meaning that I will have to use PHP or Python to CURL it then make a request to that file and get the JSON from there...Correct?

Comment: I edit my answer, you can create your own server calling their server. see  the link i published.

Comment: I think I'll just write a little server side code to handle this then I'll be good to go. Thanks for helping.